# How to extract the filename from a URL in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, url-parsing

Here's my problem I want to get the file name from the URL ex. `https://randomWebsite.com/folder/filename.jpeg` I got the expected result on javascript using this `string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/')+1)`. In Elixir I use this function `String.slice(string, <first_value_from_binary.match>..String.length(string)` ... `:binary.match()` only gets the first index of the first char that match the given letter... or is there any other solution getting the file name from the URL than this?

Comment: In [tag:elixir] there are **no arrays**, we have lists instead, and, hence, no indexes.  `"https://randomWebsite.com/folder/filename.jpeg" |> String.split("/") |> List.last()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think only need `Path.basename/1`:

```
"https://randomWebsite.com/folder/filename.jpeg"
|> Path.basename()
```

Comment: Interestingly `Path` says it is for use with "filesystem paths", but it uses [Erlang's `filename`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/filename.html#basename-1) module internally, which has a much wider scope: "With filename is meant all strings that can be used to denote a file."

Comment: Cool, Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can parse the string into a `URI` using `URI.parse/1`, get its `:path`, and call `Path.basename/1` to get the name of the last segment of the path:

```
iex(1)> "https://randomWebsite.com/folder/filename.jpeg" |> URI.parse() |> Map.fetch!(:path) |> Path.basename()
"filename.jpeg"
```

Comment: Cool Thanks. I have a question what is the difference if I just do ```"https://randomWebsite.com/folder/filename.jpeg"
|> Path.basename()``` it outputs the same value

Comment: Looking at the source code of the functions, I think `Path.basename/1` would be fine for your use case.